# Need to create multiple dataframes in nested for loops based on certain filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have main raw data of securities, out of which I need to create multiple portfolios of securities based on certain filtering criterias. I am used to working in C++, not very clear on how the below can be implemented in python.

I tried to make different dataframes using nested for-loops:

`i` - used to loop through years from 2007 to 2017 (column yr in raw data)

`j` - used to loop through regions from 1 to 4 (column Region in raw data)

```
for i in range (2007, 2018):
    for j in range (1,5):
         dfij_filter = (df['yr'] == i) & (df['Region'] == j)
         dfij = dfij[dfij_filter]
         dfij = dfij.join(dfco.groupby('ISSUER_NAME')['E_SCORE'].mean(), on = 'ISSUER_NAME', rsuffix = '_ry')
         dfij = dfij.join(dfco.groupby('ISSUER_NAME')['P_SCORE'].mean(), on = 'ISSUER_NAME', rsuffix = '_ry')
         dfij = dfij.join(dfco.groupby('ISSUER_NAME')['Q_SCORE'].mean(), on = 'ISSUER_NAME', rsuffix = '_ry')
         dfij = dfij.drop_duplicates(subset['ISSUER_NAME'], keep=False)
         dfij_E = dfij.sort_values('E_SCORE_ry', ascending = False)
         dfij_ETOP = dfij_E.iloc[:50, :]
         dfij_P = dfij.sort_values('P_SCORE_ry', ascending = False)
         dfij_PTOP = dfij_P.iloc[:50, :]
         dfij_Q = dfij.sort_values('E_SCORE_ry', ascending = False)
         dfij_QTOP = dfij_Q.iloc[:50, :]
```

I need to create different dataframes and then apply few functions on those dataframes: 
Essentially the flow is: 
Step 1: Yr filter --> 
Step 2: Region filter --> 
Step 3: Calc an average E score value, avg P score value, avg Q score value for that yr and region --> (E, P, Q are different columns)
Step 4: Arrange the securities in descending order of average E score --> 
Step 5: Pick top 50 securities and put them in a dataframe

Repeat Step 4 and 5 for P and Q scores as well.

Essentially creating 10*4*3 dataframes.

These dataframes can then be used for backtesting purposes

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work / needs to be fixed?

Comment: Thanks for your response Joerg. I do not know how to create dataframes within nested for loops. In the code above I cannot dynamically create dataframes with names such as dfij (--> df20071 for eg).
I know this can be done in dictionary but I'm not sure how that works here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store your dataframes. This has the added benefits of enabling O(1) lookup and grouping your related data. You need not use a nested loop for this, you can use `dict` + `groupby` with an input dataframe `df`:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['yr', 'region']))
```

This creates a dictionary `dfs` mapping each combination of "yr" and "region" to a dataframe. You can access the dataframe for year 2010 and region 1 via `d[(2010, 1)]`.

Now to modify your dataframes, you can simply iterate your dictionary as you would any other dictionary:

```
ETOP, PTOP, QTOP = {}, {}, {}

for key in dfs:
    dfs[key] = dfs[key].join(dfco.groupby('ISSUER_NAME')['E_SCORE'].mean(), ...)
    ...
    dfs[key]= dfs[key].drop_duplicates(subset=['ISSUER_NAME'], keep=False)
    ...
    E = dfs[key].sort_values('E_SCORE_ry', ascending = False)
    ETOP[key] = E.head(50)
    ...
```

Notice I have created dictionaries `ETOP`, `PTOP`, `QTOP` to store result dataframes, each indexed by the same `('yr', 'region')` key structure. This way, you can easily access, modify or combine results for any particular combination.

Comment: Thanks jpp. 
In line: 
dfs[key]= dfs[key].drop_duplicates(subset=['ISSUER_NAME'], keep=False) . How can I drop duplicates irrespective of case sensitivity?

Comment: You can use `dfs[key] = dfs[key][~dfs[key]['ISSUER_NAME'].str.lower().duplicated()]`. See [`pd.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in df.groupby(['yr', 'region']):
    print(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ZJS. I need to create different dataframes and then apply few functions on those dataframes:
Essentially the flow is: Yr filter --> Region filter --> Calc an average E score value for that yr and region --> arrange the securities in descending order of average E score --> Pick top 50 securities and put them in a dataframe
These dataframes can then be used for backtesting purposes.

Comment: Please add an explanation of your code, it will greatly increase the quality of the answer.